# Inject strings via Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In my class under the test `BusinessFlow` I have some private service fields and one private field with java `String` type.

In my test class I have

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BusinessFlowTest {
    // How can I mock or spy this?
    private String code = "codeValue";
    @Mock
    private Service1Api service1;
    @Mock
    private Service2Api service2;
    @InjectMocks
    private BusinessFlow flow;
    ...
}
```

`@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations greatly create mocks and inject service fields. But how can I create a mock for `code` field as Mockito doesn't allow to create a mock for `final` classes?

One option I see is to use `CharSequence` interface instead of `String` field type but it needs to change code of `BusinessFlow` class and I don't like this idea.

**UPDATE:** class `BusinessFlow` is defined like this

```
@Service
public class BusinessFlow {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "clientCode")
    private String code;

    @Autowired
    private Service1Api service1;
    @Autowired
    private Service2Api service2;

    ...
}
```

and for some reason we don't use Spring Integration tests ability and don't want to rework `BusinessFlow` in different type of injection (e.g. ctor injection)

Comment: Why do you want to mock the string? Why not just pass a value that suits your need.

Comment: @litelite because I wanna test my `BusinessFlow` with different `code` values.

Comment: Then why not just pass a different one every time you create/use your `BusinessFlow` ?

Comment: Do you know the difference between mocking and injection? And what would you like to spy on?

Comment: @litelite the reason is the same as I can't pass services values: in `BusinessFlow` Spring field injection is used to inject both services and `code` values.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun then you should mock the part responsible for the injection....

Comment: In short: [Mockito cannot mock `final` classes](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ). You should be able to spy on a `String` (at least, I do not see any reason why it should not work), but I do not see how either would help you setting the `code` within `BusinessFlow`.

Comment: @Turing85 Mockito can't spy `final` classes too. One option I've mentioned in my post. Other option I see is to use reflection to inject String value manually. The best option I see is to change field injections to good ctor injection but I wan't to do this as logically we have to do this in other flow classes to be consistent and we don't want to do this now.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun true that. Just had a look at Mockito's source code an a spy is a specialized mock, so... yeah. If you want to mock final classes, you need something else (e.g. PowerMock, but keep in mind that PowerMock messes with the byte code).

Comment: Actually, Mockito can mock final classes now... It's in Mockito 2. Not saying that it's a good idea, but sometimes you have code that you cannot refactor that make it very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Mocks are meant to mimic external dependencies which are either too prohibitive to spin up in a test context, or otherwise unnecessary to do so.  You mock things like services and DAO layer access points to ensure all you're doing is a *unit* test.

What you're wanting to do is to change the value of this field for every test you run, ***independent of your mocks***.  Remember - those mocks are external dependencies.  You can easily control* the string coming into your class.

For an example in your test:

```
@Test
public void testWithFoo() {
    // given
    flow.setValue("foo");

    // when
    // invoke a pertinent method

    // then
    // observe results
}
```

<sup>*: And if you can't, this is a good opportunity to refactor.</sup>

Comment: My team member just implemented this idea. But I don't like it as: 1. it needs to change the source class for testing purpose 2. introduces two different types of DI in one class: setter and field injection (see my update in the post).

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun:  Using `@Autowired` in that fashion is actively discouraged; you should look to use *either* constructor-based or setter-based injection instead.  However, I can't find myself complaining about the design change; I *did* mention that'd this be a good exercise for refactoring around.

Comment: In theory I agree with you but practically read this my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052208/inject-strings-via-mockito?noredirect=1#comment75130414_44052208

Answer (score 2):

It's not wise to mock data objects, or simple classes with repeatable or stateless behaviour that you know to work (like those provided by the JDK).

Field injection is discouraged because of the exact issue you are experiencing.

---

However if you choose to ignore this received wisdom, Spring does provide a utility class for this purpose: `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils`.

With this you could inject into your class with:

```
 BusinessFlow flow = new BusinessFlow();
 ReflectionTestUtils.setField(flow, "code", "testcode");
 ReflectionTestUtils.setField(flow, "service1", mockService);
```

Of course you can achieve the same thing directly using the Java Reflection API, but this is slightly more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

That's considered a really bad practice to mock anything under `java.lang` package.
Also, it's not recommended to use field injection in Spring.
The cheapest way to have control over your `Spring code` is to refactor the class to use constructor injection.

```
@Service
public class BusinessFlow {

    private String code;

    private Service1Api service1;

    private Service2Api service2;

    @Autowired
    public BusinessFlow(@Qualifier(value = "clientCode") String code,
                        Service1Api service1,
                        Service2Api service2) {
        this.code = code;
        this.service1 = service1;
        this.service2 = service2;
    }
}
```

That will cost you nothing, you don't have to change the clients of `BusinessFlow` class (as long as it's managed by Spring).
And now you can control the data that's injected to your class without using Spring test features.

```
Service1Api service1 = mock(Service1Api.class);
Service2Api service2 = mock(Service2Api.class);
BusinessFlow businessFlow = new BusinessFlow("codeValue", service1, service2);
```

Comment: First, please, read this my prev. comment why I don't want to do this refactoring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052208/inject-strings-via-mockito#comment75130414_44052208 Second, my colleagues always arguing me why we should to introduce more complex ctor injection as we can reach the same goal with less verbose field injection? :(

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun Of course you can reach the same goal with field injection. Well, almost the same goal. Here you have one perfect example why the ctor injection is better to use: you can easily test your class and don't even have to use any mock libraries. However, you can always use Spring test features to provide fake beans instead of the real ones.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun You can also use the reflection to inject the value to your filed. But in this case you rely on implementation of your class. That's not a good practice. You should test the behavior not the implementation.

Comment: Spring test beans approach is the worth option as make my unit test into integration test involving Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

use apache commons reflection method to initialise string value in your test class as below

FieldUtils.writeField(classObject, "variableName", "value", true);